# Forward sip call to number

Tags: asterisk, sip, sip-server

I want to forward sip call like this :

```
----------
1001 User1
1002 User2
2001 User3
3001 User4
----------
```

When `User1 (1001)` call 1, I want to forward call to `User3 (2001)`.

When `User2 (1002)` call 1, I want to forward call to `User4 (3001)`.

Anybody know how can I do that in asterisk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do DIFFERENT dialplan for each user.

Something like this

```
[from-internal]
exten => 1/1001,1,Dial(SIP/2001,,o); extension  1 callerid 1001
exten => 1/1002,1,Dial(SIP/3001,,o);extension 1 callerid 1002
```